# Subfigure and \textwidth not working correctly

Tags: floats, subfloats, overleaf, subcaption

I want to use subfigure to put one image next to the other in my document. I literally copy-pasted the code from [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_3)%3A_Figures%2C_Subfigures_and_Tables#Subfigures) and modified it to have 2 instead of 3 images. I am working on Overleaf directly and it did not work, with the following errors:

> Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> ```
>                } l.20      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
> ```
>
> A number should have been here; I inserted 0. (If you can't figure out
> why I needed to see a number, look up `weird error' in the index to
> The TeXbook.)

and

> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)
>
> }
> l.27      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}

> Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc, cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one! I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points. To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to delete the erroneous units; e.g., type 2 to delete two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

I tried to just copy-paste literally and use 2 times the same image, but the same errors show up.

```
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/body/hierarchical-clustering-sklearn.png}
         \caption{$y=x$}
         \label{fig:y equals x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/body/partition-sklearn.png}
         \caption{$y=3\sin x$}
         \label{fig:three sin x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/body/partition-sklearn.png}
         \caption{$y=5/x$}
         \label{fig:five over x}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}
```

Edit 1: I do have graphicx loaded in the preamble.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE community! Please extend/merge your code fragments to complete small document, which we can copy to our computers and compile as it is.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Your code fragment inserted in small complete document work fine (no warning, no bad boxes, no errors) and result is as expected to be. So. it seems that you have problem with document preamble or it arise from somewhere from not included in your code fragment or your image files are ill defined.

Comment: did you include
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}?

you should not use \usepackage{subfigure} as the subfigure environment works a bit differently there

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the errors if I run LaTeX on

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
         \caption{$y=x$}
         \label{fig:y equals x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
         \caption{$y=3\sin x$}
         \label{fig:three sin x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
         \caption{$y=5/x$}
         \label{fig:five over x}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The package `subfigure` has been obsolete for about two decades and was replaced by `subfig`. Anyway, you're using the syntax of `subcaption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}          
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
         \caption{$y=x$}
         \label{fig:y equals x}
     \end{subfigure}\hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
         \caption{$y=3\sin x$}
         \label{fig:three sin x}
     \end{subfigure}\hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
         \caption{$y=5/x$}
         \label{fig:five over x}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that I removed the useless `\centering` commands inside `subfigure`. I also replaced the file names for the image with something I have.

Note also the correct syntax for `\hfill` (you had a space in excess caused by the endline).

[image]